# Defining a function that converts a list of lists into separate lists?

Tags: python, list, function

I am trying to create a defined function using a for-loop that receives as input a list of lists, and converts them to separate lists.

```
def convert_to_sep_lists(listoflists):
    for i in range(len(listoflists)):
        newlst=listoflists[i]
```

This would obviously return the very last list in the list of lists. How can I save every iteration and return all the lists (within that list) separately?

Comment: You could store the sublists in a list. :)

Comment: I can't think of any use of why do want to do this. Can you please tell what are you going to accomplish after separating to different lists?

Comment: A function can only return one value; that value might be a collection like a tuple (or a list), but it's still *one* value.

Comment: So if I call `convert_to_sep_lists([[1,2], [3,4]])`, what should happen? Do you want a new set of names available after the call, like `list_1` and `list_2` which refer to `[1,2]` and `[3,4]` respectively? That's a very bad idea for a number of reasons, the two biggest one being 1) How do you know what names get created and 2) How do you avoid overwriting an existing name?

Comment: @amulya349 I have a college assignment due, which is supposed to analyze some data and statistics. The professor has provided us with a code that takes the data from a csv file and converts it into a very long list of lists in python. He recommended to us that we break them apart into separate lists but I have no clue how to do so.

Comment: @chepner that's exactly what I was thinking.. you make a very valid point. That's why I was initially confused

Answer (score 0):

you can try pandas to_json function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n=20
columns_name = list('abcd')
df = pd.DataFrame(data = np.random.randint(1,100,size=(5,4)),
              columns= columns_name)
print(df)
df.sum().to_json("result.json")
```

The dataframe df content will be:

```
    a   b   c   d
0  56  91  65  82
1  63  65  50  78
2  46  43  75   3
3  37  96  84  13
4  40  59  61  66
```

the output file content will be

```
{"a":165,"b":230,"c":234,"d":336}
```